# Is there a name for non-chain, "standalone" stores?

Tags: vocabulary

Some stores like Delifrance, Starbuck, expand their business in my local area, but some traditional stores are going to be eliminated through competition because something happens or maybe they don't have any branches. These traditional stores are usually standalone.

In contrast with Delifrance, Starbuck, which are chain stores, what is the name given to these traditional stores? Are they are called "standalone" businesses or "standalone" stores?

Kitty

Comment: Interesting question! My (non-native) guesses would be "local businesses",  "independent shops", "corner shops". (0: I also tried some google-fu: typed in "chain stores vs." and let Google's autofill propose some options to me.

Comment: I've edited out your 'phatic' congratulations - these are gracious but would be better suited as comments [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2624/32).

Comment: I think they'd usually be referred to as the ***independents*** (or *independent stores, retailers, outlets, etc.*), not "standalone(s)".

Comment: I second FumbleFingers. *Independent* is probably the best word, if the main sense you want to convey is not just "small companies", "mom-and-pop", or "local businesses". *Independent* conveys the sense of being non-chain, non-franchised, and independently owned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a **mom and pop** store.

From this [site](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/mom-and-pop-store.html)

> A small, independent, usually family-owned, controlled, and operated
> business that has a minimum amount of employees, has only a small
> amount of business volume, and is typically not franchised, therefore
> open for business only in a single location.

More links here:

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/momandpop.asp

http://www.cnbc.com/2014/10/24/s.html

Comment: While this is true in the USA, "mom & pop" is not used in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say...

> A *local* store/restaurant

Or

> A *non-chain* store/restaurant

Comment: Local business is a common choice, but I haven't heard non-chain business used. This article talks about the types of businesses in the question https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_Austin_Weird It refers to them as local, small, and independent businesses.

Comment: Okay, after a little search - http://www.forbes.com/sites/richwinley/2015/08/31/ndas-how-to-prevent-people-from-stealing-your-idea/ @ColleenV

Comment: OK, so I searched also, and folks on the Internet do use "non-chain" when looking for locally-owned restaurants (which is how I would say it) that are unique to the city they're visiting. It doesn't seem common for other types of businesses though. Most of the articles I've read about big companies hurting "standalone" businesses use terms like "small companies", "mom-and-pop" (in the US), and "local businesses". I'm not saying non-chain is incorrect, it just seems a little awkward to me.